# store output of system command into a variable in r

Tags: r, variables, system

I am executing the following command in R :

```
system("ls ")
```

I need to store the output of the above command in some R variable.
Is there a way to do the same??

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use `intern=TRUE`:

```
a <- system("ls ", intern = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the information if one makes a system call to a program?

Comment: Is there any way to get both the os program status code and the output of the program?

Comment: What if I am shelling out to an SQL command which returns 1 million rows? How can I redirect the output to a file first?

Answer (score 8):

why not use the corresponding R function?

```
a <- list.files()
b <- list.files(recursive = TRUE)
```

For more details

```
?list.files
```

Comment: Because `list.files` also lists directories as items, and if you use `recursive=T` it dives into those directories. There is no simple R way to list _just the files_ in a directory. I use `file_list = system('ls -p <target dir> | grep -v /')`