# How do I extract the MAC ID of a laptop through R-Script code?

Tags: r, uuid, mac-address

I am new to R. I want to know how to extract MAC id of a system in R. Is there anything similar to uuid.getnode() in Python?

Comment: Use `system` or `system2` to call `ifconfig`, `ip`, or `ipconfig`, depending on whatever system you have. From there, just parse the output.

Answer (score 3):

An idea would be to run system commands from R by using `system` and storing the result in a file which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11098277/11756186).

#### On Linux

To get the MAC address in command line on Linux you would use (not tested on MAC) from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/628387/974073)

```
$ ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'
```

So the overall line in R would be :

```
mac_addr<- system("ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'", intern = TRUE)
```

#### On Windows

```
mac_addr<- system("getmac", intern = TRUE)
```

Then parse the result as proposed by @r2evans

Comment: Without the error we can not help you further.. (please do not disclose your real MAC address, IP...)

Comment: Error: '\K' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K" 
This is what it said when i tried mac_addr<- system("ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'", intern = TRUE)

Comment: I don't have a Mac so I don't know, try `mac_addr<- system("ifconfig -a", intern = TRUE). You should have a string containing the mac address. Is it the case ?

Comment: On which Operating System are you ? `getmac` is a Windows command

Comment: I am on Windows. Trying to get MAC id of laptop in R.

Comment: So the macos tag in your post has nothing to do here. Then replace the Linux command in quotes by `"getmac"` and take a look at the string given as an output.