# Why does a system call fail in R, when the output is attempted to be saved?

Tags: r, system

I tried to save the results from a System call of an environmental variable in R, following this: [store output of system command into a variable in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098277/store-output-of-system-command-into-a-variable-in-r).

(Note: I am aware i can use: `Sys.getenv()`. The call to an environmental variable is just a simplified example to Keep the question "minimal").

OS is Windows 10.

This works:

```
> system(command = "SET", intern = FALSE)
[1] 127
```

This does not:

```
> system(command = "SET", intern = TRUE)
Error in system(command = "SET", intern = TRUE) : 'SET' not found
```

This works again:

```
> system(command = "ls", intern = TRUE)
 [1] "DESCRIPTION"                                          
 [2] "NAMESPACE" 
 ...
```

**Attempts from the suggestions in the comments:**

First:

```
> system(command='echo $SET', intern=TRUE)
[1] "$SET"
```

Second:

```
> system(command = "SET", intern = TRUE, ignore.stdout = TRUE)
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 127
Warning messages:
1: In system(command = "SET", intern = TRUE, ignore.stdout = TRUE) :
  'SET' not found
2: In system(command = "SET", intern = TRUE, ignore.stdout = TRUE) :
  running command 'SET' had status 127
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Did you try `system(command='echo $SET', intern=TRUE)`?

Comment: Running `system(command = "SET", intern = TRUE, ignore.stdout = TRUE)` might be elucidating.

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast replies! OS is Windows 10, i added this info + the Outputs from your Code suggestions in my question.

Comment: See the documentation in `help("system")`, the return value of 127 indicates that the command could not be run.